# Cake build - NugetRestore with PackageReferences

Tags: nuget, cakebuild

I have a Visual Studio 2017 solution which contains .NET Standard, .NET Core, and .NET Framework projects. My .NET Framework 4.6.2 project is using PackageReferences in the .csproj file - instead of a packages.config.

This seems to be the new way of specifying NuGet packages and will allow future migration to .NET Standard 2.0 (I hope).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files

csproj:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="LanguageExt.Core">
        <Version>2.1.1</Version>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac">
          <Version>1.0.3</Version>
```

VS displays cool icons:

[image: project references]

Anyway, the solution compiles fine under Visual Studio but fails with build errors when compiling via cake.

```
Databases\DatabaseInstaller.cs(5,27): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Dac' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\code\Core.AcceptanceTesting\Core.AcceptanceTesting.csproj]
```

Are these newer "PackageReferences" supported by cake build?

Here's a segment from my cake script:

```
// NuGet restore packages for .NET Framework projects (and .NET Core projects)
Task("NuGet-Restore")
    .IsDependentOn("Clean")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        NuGetRestore(solutionFile);
    });

// NuGet restore packages for .NET Core projects only
Task("DotNetCoreRestore")
    .IsDependentOn("NuGet-Restore")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        var settings = new DotNetCoreRestoreSettings
        {
            ArgumentCustomization = args => args.Append("/p:Version=" + versionPrefix + "-" + versionSuffix)
        };
        DotNetCoreRestore(settings);
    });

// Build our solution
 Task("Build")
    .IsDependentOn("DotNetCoreRestore")
    .Does(() =>
    {
        DotNetCoreBuild(
            solutionFile,
            new DotNetCoreBuildSettings()
            {
                ArgumentCustomization = args => args.Append("/p:Version=" + versionPrefix + "-" + versionSuffix),
                Configuration = configuration
            });
    });
```

Comment: Yes they're, can you share how your doing your restore & build with your cake script?

Comment: @devlead updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your repo and got it building. Use the build definition below. Reason it works in Visual Studio is because it uses MSBuild and Nuget.exe. Don't call DotNetCoreX-commands on NET Framework.

```
Task("Build")
    .IsDependentOn("NuGet-Restore")
    .Does(() => {
        MSBuild(solutionFile);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

What version of Cake are you using?  The .Net Core aliases were recently updated to reflect some changes in the API surface.  What happens if you try the following:

```
var settings = new DotNetCoreRestoreSettings
{
    ArgumentCustomization = args => args.Append("/p:Version=" + versionPrefix + "-" + versionSuffix)
};

DotNetCoreRestore(solutionFile, settings);
```

i.e. include the path to the Solution File.

As per this example:

https://github.com/cake-contrib/Cake.Recipe/blob/develop/Cake.Recipe/Content/build.cake#L128

Comment: I'm on Cake 0.19.4. Just tried your suggestion with the latest version of Cake, 0.21.1, and I get the same error. If I convert the project to use a packages.config instead of PackageReferences it works fine

Comment: Is this on a public repo?  i.e. can we take a look?

Comment: Here's an example repo: https://github.com/mattfrear/CakeFail. Run .\build.ps1 and it will fail